# Microsoft Computer Vision API returning 404 Resource Not Found

Tags: c#, azure, computer-vision, azure-cognitive-services

I tried to call Azure's [Computer Vision API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/computer-vision/) using the C# code below but got the following response:

```
{"code":"404","message":"Resource not found"}
```

Any advice to get this work?

```cs
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using AzureFunctions.Extensions.CognitiveServices.Bindings.Vision.Analysis;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table;

namespace myCognitiveFunction
{
    public static class myCognitiveFunction
    {
        [FunctionName("myCognitiveFunction")]
        public static async Task RunAsync(

            [BlobTrigger("images/{name}", Connection = "storageAccount")]Stream myBlob,
            [VisionAnalysis(VisionKey = "Key", VisionUrl = "Url")]VisionAnalysisClient visionClient,
            [Table("VisionAnalysis", Connection = "storageAccount")]IAsyncCollector<VisionResult> results,
            string name, ILogger log)
        {
            var request = new VisionAnalysisRequest(myBlob);
            var result = await visionClient.AnalyzeAsync(request);
            var visionResult = new VisionResult(Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), "VisionAnalysis") { ResultJson = result.ToString() };

            await results.AddAsync(visionResult);
            log.LogInformation($"Results: {result.ToString()}");
        }
    }
    public class VisionResult : TableEntity
    {

        public VisionResult(string id, string partitionKey)
        {
            this.RowKey = id;
            this.PartitionKey = partitionKey;
        }

        public string ResultJson { get; set; }

    }
}
```

Url: https://mycognitive1000.cognitiveservices.azure.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, Welcome to SO! It seems you've copied the code from the documentation without replacing the placeholders namely `storageAccount`,`Key`,`Url`... which are required for the service to work. For example, in your case, the URL posted under your question should go in the `VisionUrl` property as follows:

```
[VisionAnalysis(VisionKey = "YOUR_KEY", VisionUrl = "mycognitive1000.cognitiveservices.azure.com")]
```

The storage account is an [Azure Blob Storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-dotnet) connection string. As for the Vision Key and Url, you can find a good tutorial and documentation on the [Computer Vision API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/computer-vision/tutorials/storage-lab-tutorial) in the official docs. The tutorial explains as well how to have those parameters written within a separate configuration file as a best practice.